# dismissViewController for navigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c

Right now I have a cancel button and when i click the cancel button i don't want the name to be displayed on the tableview cell. So if I do `[self.navigaitonController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` it works properly but adds the name to the tableviewcontroller which i don't want if i do `[self.navigationController dimissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]` the cancel button doesn't do anything. My problem is that, if I press the cancel button it still adds the name to the tableviewcell. What is the best workaround this?

```
- (void)cancelButtonPressed:(id)sender
{

    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Please describe problem more precisely, problem that cancel doesn't work or the name will be added?

Comment: ? I stated it clearly

Answer (score 0):

`popViewController` is to pop a view off of the `UINavigationController`'s stack, whereas `dismissViewController` is only for *modal* views. So if you want to present your tableview without a navigation bar (which is what I'm assuming you're trying to do?), use the navigation controller to present it modally instead of pushing it onto the stack. This is do by using `presentViewController` instead of `pushViewController`. Then it should respond to `dismissViewController`.

Comment: Yes I understand that that's why dismissViewController isn't working. When I click the cancel button I don't want the name to display back on the tableviewcontroller because if i do popViewController and press cancel it popsback up to the tableviewcontroller and stills show the name added

Comment: Say for example I have a tableviewcontroller and on the controller it has an add button. I click the add button and it takes me to another page with add a contact. On that page there is a save and cancel button. If I press cancel, the default name still shows in the tableviewcell

Comment: Umm, then maybe you're saving your contact model when you push the screen instead of saving it only after you tap save? That's the only explanation I can think of. Where exactly in the contact adding page controller are you saving the contact info?